# OAuth callback through HTTP (not SSL) is possible?

Tags: security, oauth2, oauth, connected-apps

### In short:

I need to set a **Connected App** to later use OAuth Web server Flow.
The callback URL should be HTTP. My web server **does not have a SSL certificate** and I not able to get one. But SF give me an error if I want to use HTTP.

1. Is it possible to set http?
2. Any workaround?

### So far:

When I put the http url like this:

[image]

I get this error:

[image]

I've tried to use https without a certificate but the problem is that the browser will block the request showing the typical alert page like this:

[image]

Comment: Why are you not able to get an SSL cert?

Comment: That is because we are trying a proof of concept of a free service and is not budget to buy that :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - the only callback you can use with plain HTTP is localhost. This is to ensure the security of the tokens.

Comment: I'm affray you are right. But I found a workaround using a heroku app as pivot host. Heroku has free https and hence making a redirection there was a pice of cake :D

Comment: I was going to suggest exactly that course of action :-)